Is it possible to control QComboBox currentIndex from model?
I'm diving into the capabilities Qt Model/View and want to implement a model (or reuse QStandardItemModel if possible) to control a QComboBox. I have a bunch of items represented by strings, which have data, order, enabled state, and also the item currently in charge driven by the model. The in-charge item should be the selected one after model update, so I thought the model should get means to control currentIndex of the QComboBox.
Browsing the Qt documentation and sources (version 5, but I could also go for version 6 if required) did not reveal any hints how to achieve my goal.

A model has no access to the view and the current index is a property of the view - so no.

A data model has no (nor should have) awareness or references of any of its views, just like a string doesn't know what will ever print/show it. Yet, nothing prevents you to create a QStandardItemModel (or QAbstractListModel/QAbstractTableModel) subclass with a custom property or function that returns the possible default index, then it's just a matter of connecting the model signals (eg. rowsInserted, layoutChanged, modelReset, depending on how the model is updated) to a related function/slot that will eventually use the above property/function and eventually update the current index.

In fact, you could even create a custom signal for the model subclass (eg. defaultIndexChanged) and emit it when the model is updated, either overriding the virtual functions you may use for the update (and emitting the signal after calling the base implementation), or just internally connect related signals such as the above ones to a function that will emit the custom signal on its own.

@chehrlic Do I understand correctly that it is a Qt design decision to limit view models to not define an in-charge item that may be presented as current index or similar? If yes, I'm going to adapt musicamante's suggestion.

As I wrote I don't see why a model should have access to a specific view as a model can be used by different views simultaneously.
